# html <select> dropdown - how to disable mobile overlay

Tags: html, select, mobile, overlay, disable

I have a dropdown box that works fine on desktop, however, on mobile it opens a full screen overlay with all of the options. I'd like to bypass that overlay and use the standard dropdown as it is on desktop. Is there a way programmatically to do this in Jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use a CSS only dropdown list. This way you can preserve the same dropdown from a desktop to a mobile.

Here is the reference: [Responsive mobile dropdown navigation using css only](https://medium.com/creative-technology-concepts-code/responsive-mobile-dropdown-navigation-using-css-only-7218e4498a99)

Comment: That example is for navigation, not a `<select>` form element.

Comment: Actually this is better than what I was doing. I'm creating the items dynamically with a loop, so I thought the select/dropdown way would be easier, but it seems I can do the same thing with <ul>  <li> <span> in my .html append in place of <select> and <option>. Now I'm all set!